# I want to display the updated quantity without reload page

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

> It's the controller code. I want to get and display updated quantity data without reloading the page. but I have no idea how I will do this. I am new in Js And ajax.

```
 [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddToCart(string Id)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
            if (Id == null)
            {
                var applicationDbContext = _context.AddToCart.Where(u => u.UserId == user.Id).Include(p => p.Products);
                return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
            }
            else
            {
                var ProductId = _context.AddToCart.Where(p => p.ProductsId == Id && p.UserId == user.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                if (ProductId == null)
                {
                    AddToCart a = new AddToCart();
                    a.ProductsId = Id;
                    a.UserId = user.Id;
                    a.Add_Date = DateTime.Today;
                    a.Quantity = 1;
                    _context.AddToCart.Add(a);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    var applicationDbContext = _context.AddToCart.Where(u => u.UserId == user.Id).Include(p => p.Products);
                    return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
                }
                else
                {
                    var applicationDbContext = _context.AddToCart.Where(u => u.UserId == user.Id).Include(p => p.Products);
                    return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
                }
            }
        }
```

> it's my view code. I want to get and display updated quantity data without reloading the page. but I have no idea how I will do this. I am new in Js And ajax.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AddToCart";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>Add To Cart</h1>

<table class="table">
    @*<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.Image_path)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.Price)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.Price)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products.Product_Name)
                </th>

            </tr>
        </thead>*@
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="~/Images/@item.Products.Image_path" class="img-fluid" style="height:100px;width:170px;" asp-append-version="true" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <b>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Products.Product_Name)
                </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <text id="quantity"></text>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Products.Price)
            </td>
            <td>

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="-" class="button-minus" data-field="quantity">
                    <input type="button" id="plus" step="1" max="" min="1" value="@item.Quantity" name="quantity" asp-for="@item.Quantity" class="quantity-field">
                    <input type="submit" value="+" class="button-plus" data-field="quantity">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Id" id="itemId" value="@item.Id" data-field="quantity" />
                </div>

            </td>
            <td id="quantity">               
            </td>
            <td>
                @(item.Quantity* item.Products.Price)
            </td>

            <td>
                <form asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-success="deleteItem(this)">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger d-none d-md-inline-block">
                        Delete
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>

        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><b>Sub Total</b></td>
            <td>@Model.Sum(i => i.Quantity * i.Products.Price) TK</td>
            <td><a asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Index">Order Now</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

</table>
```

> And it is my JS code for update the quantity in the database without reloading and it is working.

```
function incrementValue(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
    var parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
    var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);

    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
        parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
}

function decrementValue(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
    var parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
    var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);

    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1) {
        parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
        parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(1);
    }
}
$('.input-group').on('click', '.button-plus', function (e) {
    //debugger
    incrementValue(e);
    var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
    var parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
    var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);
    var Id = (parent.find('input[name=Id ]').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'AddToCart', type: 'POST', data: { "value": currentVal, "Id": Id }, dataType: 'json', success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.data); $('.quantity-field').val(response.data.Quantity); } })
});



$('.input-group').on('click', '.button-minus', function (e) {
    decrementValue(e);
    var fieldName = $(e.target).data('field');
    var parent = $(e.target).closest('div');
    var currentVal = parseInt(parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(), 10);
    var id = (parent.find('input[name=Id ]').val());
    $.ajax({ url: 'AddToCart', type: 'POST', data: { "value": currentVal, "Id": id }, dataType: 'json', success: function (data) { console.log(data);
            var total = 0;
            $.each(data.data, function (k, val) {
                total += parseInt(val.quantity);
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Only change this `success: function (response) { console.log(response.data);$('.quantity-field').val(response.data.Quantity);`

Comment: Hi @Md.YounusBapary, can you share the code of `AddToCart` class?

Comment: public class AddToCart
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string ProductsId { get; set; }

        public DateTime Add_Date { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public Product Products { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    }

Comment: Hi @Md.YounusBapary, you can check my post with testing sample.

Comment: r.send(i.hasContent && i.data || null). still now i am getting an error.

Comment: @Fei Han Link Please

Comment: `r.send(i.hasContent && i.data || null)` What is it? `getting an error` and what is the error?

Comment: I want to send you an Error picture. how I will send it?

Comment: If you can not share error picture, you can include detailed error message in your posted thread. So that we can help troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: Hi @Md.YounusBapary, any updates?

Comment: Hi @FeiHan. I am really sorry about that. I updated my code its not working still now. please check my updated code and give me a solution. It will be a honor for me from you. please help me.

Comment: `not working still now` any error or exception? Besides, [HttpGet] attribute that constrains matching to HTTP GET requests only, please share the code of your `AddToCart` action method that you use to process js client post request.

Comment: @Fei Han  AddToCart action method code has been given the top on the page.

Comment: You applied `[HttpGet]` attribute that constrains matching to HTTP GET requests only, but your js client make request with `POST` method, are you sure request reaches into that action?

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddToCart(string Id, int value)
        { var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(User.Identity.Name);
            var AddToCartId = _context.AddToCart.Where(p => p.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (AddToCartId != null)
            {
                AddToCart a = await _context.AddToCart.Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                a.Quantity = value;
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return Json("ok");
            }
            return View();
        }

Comment: it' my update quantity AddToCart method code

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your define `AddToCart` class with `Id` and `Quantity` etc properties like below.

```
public class AddToCart
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    //...
    //other properties
    //...
}
```

Your `GetData` action method would return data with list of `AddToCart` object in it, like below.

[image]

To get total quantities and update specific element with updated quantities on JS client side, you can try the following code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Home/GetData',
    data: { Id: empId },
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'Json',
    success: function (data) {     
        console.log(data);

        var total = 0;

        $.each(data.data, function (k,val) {
            total += parseInt(val.quantity);
        });

        //console.log(total);

        $('.quantity-field').val(total);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

Besides, you can also do calculation on server side to include total quantities in return data.

```
return Json(new { data = AddToCartList, total = AddToCartList.Sum(p => p.Quantity) });
```

On client side, you can get it via `data.total`.

```
success: function (data) {     
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.total);
    var total = data.total;
```